# PHP Comtrust SOAP api Response Code 5000

Tags: php, soap, payment-gateway, soap-client

I am using Comtrust payment api and developing a SOAP wrapper to call Comtrust functions. And currently using demo account of Comtrust by following their documentation and getting following response:

```
stdClass Object ( [RegisterResult] => stdClass Object ( [ResponseCode] => 5000 [ResponseDescription] => Request is not permitted or not authenticated properly [UniqueID] => 1942d0d0-37f5-4504-951e-3343f9b86ea7 [version] => 2.0 [PaymentPortal] => [TransactionID] => ) )
```

I am using following code:

```
 $client = new SoapClient("https://demo-ipg.comtrust.ae:2443/MerchantAPI.svc?singleWsdl");
    try {

        $result = $client->Register(array("request" => array(
            'Customer' => 'Demo Merchant',
            'Channel' => 'Web',
            'Address'   => 'demo-ipg.comtrust.ae',             
            'Language' => 'en',
            'Password' => 'Comtrust',
            'version' => '2.0',
            'Amount' => '99.98',
            'Currency' => 'AED',
            'OrderID' => '123',
            'OrderInfo' => 'Test Info',
            'OrderName' => 'Test Name',
            'ReturnPath' => 'http://127.0.0.1/jd_ecommerce/',
            'TransactionHint' => 'CPT:Y'
       )));
        print_r($result);
    }catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

I have certificate file which is in .pfx format and password. My question is how to pass .pfx file with SOAP envelop. Is any one face similar issue?

Please help!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you need to use certificate in .pem format. please use it with password “Comtrust” to access staging server.